# How to copy file from zipArchive into another zipArchive without unzipping - in c#

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I want to get an entry from `zipArchive1` added to `zipArchive2` without unzipping `zipArchive1`.

```
using (var zipArchive1 = ZipFile.Open(zipFile1, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    using (var zipArchive2 = ZipFile.Open(zipFile2, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        var entry = zipArchive1.GetEntry("fileName");
        
        // I want to do something like
        // zipArchive2.Add(entry) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so what error did you get out of what you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Srecko Ristic's proposal below works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
using (ZipArchive sourceArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceZip))
{
    var entry = sourceArchive.GetEntry(fileFromSource);
    using (ZipArchive destArchive = ZipFile.Open(destZip, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        using (var existinFileStream = entry.Open())
        {
            var newFile = destArchive.CreateEntry(entry.FullName);
            using (var newFileStream = newFile.Open())
            {
                existinFileStream.CopyTo(newFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `sourceZip` and `destZip` are paths to your zip files and `fileFromSource` is name of the file in source archive.