# Need help in read zip files and changes specified text file contents using C#(web form )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, zip

I want to write a program that can read a zip file and then find the specified file (e.g. find aaa.txt) and then change all the content of the file (e.g. 111 to 222).

I've searched on google for a long time but I can't do it and I can't find any suitable example.

I've read some tutorials and tried to do it, but it's still not working.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

                if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".zip")
                {
                    //Response.Write(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName));
                    using (FileStream zipToOpen = new FileStream(FileUpload1.FileName, FileMode.Open))   
                    {                                                                 
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(readmeEntry.Open()))
                            {
                                string text = File.ReadAllText(zipToOpen);              
                                text = text.Replace("aaa", "bbb");
                                writer.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: You can't modify a zip file in place. You have to read one zip file and write a new zip file.

Comment: Is there any good way to read the text file in the zip and modify it?

Comment: There are plenty of examples online for how to read / write `ZipArchive`'s (eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/69033531/4139809)

Comment: This is a good example of read/extract, and I've tested it. But what I want is about the code of modify text file in the zipfile, not just to read/extract.

Comment: Looks like you have to extract the files. modify the file, and then zip things back up.

Comment: Yes, just like you said.